# field is String || field is FieldPath

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can I fix this?

I want to login with id and password, but I get the following error:

> E/flutter (  985): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart': Failed assertion: line 69 pos 12: 'field is String || field is FieldPath': Supported [field] types are [String] and [FieldPath]

```
adminlogin() {
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Admins').get().then((snapshot) {
  snapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
    if (result.get(['id']) != AdminID_controller.text.trim()) {
      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
      Scaffold.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("id is incorrect")));
    } else if (result.get(['password']) !=
        PasswordAdmin_controller.text.trim()) {
      Scaffold.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Password is incorrect")));
    } else {
      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text(" welcome" + result.get(['name']))));
    }
  });
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with this statement: `result.get(['id'])`. The `get` function of the [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot-class.html) class is meant to take a `String` or `FieldPath` as the documentation states. You are passing a `List` instead by adding the brackets. Remove the brackets.

```
result.get('id')
```

---

The reason you're not getting a static analysis error is because the parameter of the `get` function is declared as `dynamic` so that it can take either a `String` or `FieldPath` object. Functions with dynamic parameters are usually done so that they can take objects of different types in the same position. Another example would be the `jsonEncode` function. However, it's import to pay attention to what data types the documentation states they can actually take.

Comment: @DawanMahmud please upvote/accept the answer if it solves your problem.